# Setting parallelism of `ParallelFor` in Vertex AI dynamically, based on the pipeline parameter

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I have a Vertex AI pipeline that takes in a country argument (a string such as "uk", or "de"...). The first task of the pipeline `get_country_dr_keys` generates all "dr keys" (what that stands for is irrelevant here) that need to be processed for that country. The output of that then feeds into `ParallelFor`, i.e. the pipeline branches out once for each dr key.

What I'd like to do is to set the `parallelism` of that `ParallelFor` loop ***based on the country***. I.e. do something like this:

```
    def jxp_country_pipeline(country_str: str):
        get_country_dr_keys_task = get_country_dr_keys(country_str=country_str)

        dr_keys_loop = ParallelFor(
            items=get_country_dr_keys_task.output,
            name="jxp-dr-loop",
            parallelism=work_out_parallelism(country_str=country_str),
        )
        with dr_keys_loop as dr_key:
            jxp_dr_pipeline(dr_key=dr_key)
```

The problem is that the pipeline does not compile, it seems that the parallelism is set at the compile time, i.e. the function `work_out_parallelism` is ran at compile time, when the `country_str` parameter isn't available yet.

Is there a way to determine and set the `parallelism` dynamically, e.g. based on the value of the pipeline parameter `country_str`, or at least the length of the output of `dr_keys_loop`?